# APEX custom database authentication

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Currently I am using database accounts as my authentication schema and as a result anyone with a valid database account may login. I would like this to be more restrictive. All my users have a prefix in their user account names which specifies the group they belong to. An example would be dev_john, qa_cindy, etc. I would only like a specific group with a certain prefix in their username to be able to login. Database accounts seems to just allow all. I see there is a custom auth, but I am unsure how to get databse users from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with this would be how to check the Oracle users' passwords from within your custom authentication function.  Hopefully there is no way you can **find out** their passwords to check them, so how can you establish they typed the correct password?  Maybe there is a way, I don't know.

However, perhaps more appropriate for this rule would be an **authorization** scheme.  The user can log in, but if their username fails your authorization scheme test, they can't access the application.  The test would be a PL/SQL expression like:

```
:APP_USER like 'QA%' or :APP_USER like 'TEST%'
```

When user DEV_JOHN logs in, the log in succeeds but all they get is a page saying e.g.

> Only QA and TEST users are allowed to access this system.

Comment: Thanks works beautifully! I never thought to use authorization scheme, was thinking only authentication.